# Simple ODEs - Solving Using Annihilators and Factoring into Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble conceptually understanding a line in Step 2 in the following solution:

$$
\text { Solve } y^{\prime \prime}+3 y^{\prime}+2 y=4 x^{2}
$$

- **Step 1**: Solving Homogeneous $y^{\prime \prime}+3 y^{\prime}+2 y=0$. From auxiliary equation $m^{2}+3 m+2=(m+1)(m+2)=0$ we get $m_{1}=-1$ and $m_{2}=-2$ thus complementary function:
  $$
  y_{c}=c_{1} e^{-x}+c_{2} e^{-2 x}
  $$
- **Step 2**: Since $4x^2$ is annihilated by differential operator $ D^3 $, we see that $D^{3}\left(D^{2}+3 D+2\right) y=4 D^{3} x^{2}$ is the same as 
  $$
  D^{3}\left(D^{2}+3 D+2\right) y=0
  $$
  The auxiliary equation of this fifth-order equation
  $$
  m^{3}\left(m^{2}+3 m+2\right)=0 \quad \text { or } \quad m^{3}(m+1)(m+2)=0
  $$
  Q: This part completely lost me. I understand the basic operations of the differential operator and that it can reduce a lower order function to zero. $4 D^{3} x^{2}$ makes sense to me, but I have no idea how that turned into $D^{3}\left(D^{2}+3 D+2\right) y=4 D^{3} x^{2}$.
  I'll add the rest of the solution for completion.

---

has roots $m_{1}=m_{2}=m_{3}=0, m_{4}=-1,$ and $m_{5}=-2$. Thus
$$
y=c_{1}+c_{2} x+c_{3} x^{2}+c_{4} e^{-x}+c_{5} e^{-2 x}
$$

$$
y_{p}=A+B x+C x^{2}
$$
$$
y_{p}^{\prime}=B+2 C x, \quad y_{p}^{\prime \prime}=2 C
$$

$$
y_{p}^{\prime \prime}+3 y_{p}^{\prime}+2 y_{p}=2 C+3 B+6 C x+2 A+2 B x+2 C x^{2}=4 x^{2}
$$
$$
2 C=4, \quad 2 B+6 C=0, \quad 2 A+3 B+2 C=0
$$

$y_{p}=7-6 x+2 x^{2}$ and thus, general solution (**Step 3**):
$$
y=c_{1} e^{-x}+c_{2} e^{-2 x}+7-6 x+2 x^{2}
$$

Comment: They are just applying $D^3$ on both sides of $(D^2  +3D+2)y = 4x^2$.

Comment: Where did $D^{2}+3 D+2$ even come from though? It looks like the auxiliary equation $m^{2}+3 m+2$ replaced with differential operator but I'm not sure why

Comment: Okay, so it seems that you are not familiar with the use of $D$. You don't have want use it. Just differentiate $y'' + 3y' +2y = 4x^2$ on both sides three times to obtain $y^{(5)} + 3y^{(4)} + 2y^{(3)} = 0$.

Comment: AH I see what's going on. $\left(D^{2}+3 D+2\right) y$ is literally doing nothing but re-writing with differential operator. I thought it had to do with the characteristic equation ( which happens to be the same).

Comment: @ArcticChar - continuing with roots $m_{1}=m_{2}=m_{3}=0, m_{4}=-1,$ and $m_{5}=-2$, shouldn't the general solution be $ e $ to -2 power?

Comment: $m_1=m_2 = m_3 = 0$ gives $a+bt+ct^2$, $m_4$ gives $e^{-t}$, $m_5$ gives $e^{-2t}$.

Answer (score 1):

By operating with $D^2$ on the original ODE you have made it order 5, so it has 5 undetermined constants. As the original ODE is second order and in-homogeneous it has only two undetermined constants. In bot the cases the correct common feature is that
the solution is a linear combination of a quadratic and two exponnentials.

So no discrepancy whatsoever.